# Get program start time from core file

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

I have a core file from a long running process. It would help me to have the start time of that process.

Is there a way under linux, using gdb to get a process start time only from core file?

Thanks

Comment: What long running program is it? Do you have its source code?

Comment: Yes, I have its source code. I will add timestamp to start for future. However it will not help me with the current core file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way under linux, using gdb to get a process start time only from core file?

I don't think so. However, see [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) & [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and run the [file(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) command on your `core` file.

In the future, you might use `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` (at system startup time). The `%t` gives the time of *dump* (not the start time).

I guess you have the source code of the core-dumping executable (otherwise, inspecting the core is in practice not very helpful).

I suggest to improve the source of your long-running program to put the result of [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html) into a global or static variable, near the start of `main`.
You probably want also to put a timestamp inside your source code.

---

<sup>here is a trick to get a timestamp (of your source code), assuming you are building with `make` and using `git` as version control:</sup>

Either use just using `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` in some C or C++ file, or more probably an additional *generated* C file containing the date and e.g. the current `git commit` log. If you use `make` feel free do add some rule like

```
_timestamp.c: Makefile
        @date +'const char my_timestamp[]="%c";' > _timestamp.tmp
        @(echo -n 'const char my_lastgitcommit[]="' ; \
           git log --format=oneline --abbrev=12 --abbrev-commit -q  \
             | head -1 | tr -d '\n\r\f\"\\\\' ; \
           echo '";') >> _timestamp.tmp
        @(echo -n 'const char my_lastgittag[]="'; \
           (git describe --abbrev=0 --all || echo '*notag*') | \
             tr -d '\n\r\f\"\\\\'; echo '";') >> _timestamp.tmp
        @mv _timestamp.tmp _timestamp.c
```

in your `Makefile` (and in the rule building your executable, link it with also `_timestamp.o` and add `$(RM) _timestamp.c` in its recipes).

---

I recommend, for long-running programs such as servers (or batch numerical code running for days), to use [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) facilities inside them. Some initial `syslog` might show `my_timestamp`, `my_lastgitcommit`, `my_lastgittag` as generated in `_timestamp.c` above.

Comment: Thanks, I was searching the internet and also found that it can not be done only from core file. I will keep this open for a while to see if someone else know how to do this and if no YES answer is added then I will accept your answer